# Check for relative URL in JavaScript before redirecting

Tags: javascript, url-routing

I'm wanting to do a check in JavaScript that the URL passed in to redirect to is a relative URL and not an absolute one.

I've looking at doing something similar to this snippet though would like to know if there is a better way of achieving this?

```js
var relativePath = document.location.hash.substring(1);
var re = new RegExp("^/[a-z0-9/.]+$");
if (re.test(relativePath)) {
  document.location = relativePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check what the url starts with rather than what it contains, and RegEx isn't required either. Basically, all absolute URL's will start with "http://" or "https://" while relative ones will not.